# Widening a garage door

Tags: garage

I have a garage and I'm planning to buy a new car. The problem is that the width of car is 5 feet and 6 inches and my garage door width is 6 feet.

So I want to know that what can I do to broaden the width of my garage door.

I called an architect. He told me to trim both the walls around 4 inches each side. But my wall is only 10.5 inches each side so can I trim the wall?

My house is double story, so can I trim my walls and my house will be still be OK?

Comment: You may be able to, but to know the conditions of your garage wall are most important. Can you post pictures of your garage door that you wish to trim?  The pictures must show the framing in the wall. If it is finished on both sides, one side will need to be remove to a degree. The fix may sound easy but the door has certain requirements for strength that cannot be violated.

Comment: A picture of the foundation is important also. If it is not constructed properly in the place the door is trimmed to, will make it very difficult. It will be better to get a reputable local contractor to give an evaluation.

Comment: Garage DOOR width or is that the entire width of your garage? If the latter, I'd say that's not a garage designed for a car. That's more of a storage shed or bike garage.

Comment: Yes, important difference, is the door too narrow or the actual walls of the structure. If you trim 4 inches off the walls, what is going to be left to hold up the roof???? not sure what you are asking for.

Comment: Is it the actual car that's too wide or the mirrors? I used to have to fold both  mirrors in to get my car in my old garage, it was a tight fit, but I managed it for 2 years without scraping the sides of the car though my wife snagged a mirror once  when she forgot to fold it in (fortunately, it just folded itself backwards with no damage). If you gain 4" on each side from folding  in the mirrors, that gives you 7 inches on each side, which is doable.

Answer (score 2):

The professional service you need is that of a structural engineer, in combination with a contractor or builder.  Each professional has a contribution to make and can enhance the work of the other.

Internet advice does not suffice for altering structural members in a home.

You can get general advice on feasibility by posting photos annotated with dimensions.  Ensure that if you widen the door, that the garage itself is large enough that you can open the car doors (unless you enjoy exiting via the sunroof).